# Elasticsearch geo_point query_parsing_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to follow the example in the documentation by indexing a single document:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/graph/nodes/1' -d'
{        
    "pin" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 40.12,
            "lon" : -71.34
        }
    }
}
'
```

This gives the mappings:

```
{
  "graph" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "nodes" : {
        "properties" : {
          "location" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "pin" : {
            "properties" : {
              "location" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "lat" : {
                    "type" : "double"
                  },
                  "lon" : {
                    "type" : "double"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "text" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to query by distance from a point it gives an error like such:

```
failed to find geo_point field [pin.location]
```

The query I am giving is the following:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/graph/_search?pretty' -d'
{
  "query" : {
    "bool":{
      "must":{
        "match_all":{}
      },
      "filter":{
        "geo_distance":{
          "distance":"200km",
            "pin.location":{
              "lat":40,
              "lon":-70
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

I am not sure where I went wrong here so any advice would be great!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Geo queries, your location needs to be geo_point or geo_shape type.

change your mapping to

```
"pin" : {
        "properties" : {
            "location" : {
              "type" : "geo_point"
               }
            }
        }
```